# How to make TabNavigator Scrollable

Tags: react-native

I am using TabNavigation and I am having **more than 5 tabs** .So horizontally my text my Tabs are getting smaller .So I want to make my TabNavigator scrollable. So is there any way I can do that . And yes I already used  **scrollEnabled: true** inside my **tabBarOptions** but nothing happened.I am very new to React Native and I don't know much of a property of TabNavigator .Any help will be useful thank you in advance.

**Edit :** I have checked both of my version Android and IOS. In Android scrollableTabs are working fine but in IOS there is no scroll.

`const TabNavigation = TabNavigator(
            {
              TabItem1: {
                    screen: ProfileDetailScreen,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        tabBarLabel: "CURRENT EVENTS",
                    }
                },
                TabItem2: {
                    screen: ProfileDetailScreen,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        tabBarLabel: "OPEN INVITATION",
                    }
                },
                TabItem3: {
                    screen: ProfileDetailScreen,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        tabBarLabel: "ACCEPTED INVITATION",
                    }
                },
                TabItem4: {
                    screen: ProfileDetailScreen,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        tabBarLabel: "MY EVENTS",
                    }
                },
                TabItem5: {
                    screen: ProfileDetailScreen,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        tabBarLabel: "PAST EVENTS",
                    }
                }
            },
            { tabBarPosition: "top",
                swipeEnabled:false,
                animateStyle:false,
                tabBarOptions: {
                    scrollEnabled: true,
                    activeTintColor: Colors.goldColor,
                    inactiveTintColor: Colors.goldColor,
                    upperCaseLabel: false,
                    showIcon: false,
                    showLabel :true,
                    labelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        marginBottom:5,
                        padding: 0
                    },
                    style: {
                        backgroundColor: 'black',
                        height: 50,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    indicatorStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: 'black',
                    },
                }
            }`

Comment: can you upload your code .. you might be missing something ....because scrollEnabled works fine in my code.

Comment: scrollEnabled: true
not working with ios ..

Answer (score 6):

Should pass the scrollEnabled inside tabBarOption

```
export const Tabs = TabNavigator({},{
    'lazy': true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        scrollEnabled: true
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: How to pass in v5 ?

Answer (score 0):

With v5, you can pass it in screenOptions -

```
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBar={(props: TabBarProps) => <Tabs {...props} />}
  screenOptions={{
    lazy: true,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
    tabBarItemStyle: { width: 150 },
  }}>
    {Tabs}
</Tab.Navigator>
```